# Try to create a Git remote repository in the same Domain but failed

Tags: git, repository, push, samba

I have two computers in one domain, one is Linux and the other one is windows. I build a remote repo on Linux, which URL is `10.10.10.1/test`, I use `git init --bare` to build this repo and no error report.

And on windows site I have a local repo and I submit files in already. Then I give following cmds:

```
$ git remote add origin 10.10.10.1/test
```

and I checked:

```
$ git remote -v
origin 10.10.10.1/test (fetch)
origin 10.10.10.1/test (push)
```

then I try to push my master to origin

```
$ git push origin master
```

I got

```
fatal: '10.10.10.1/test' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried on local windows with the same process and it works, I also try on `Github` and it works, too, so I think the problem is that I gave the wrong URL. 
I can ping 10.10.10.1 from local and I can find the folder /test as well, I tried the following cmds and they doesn't work either.

```
git remote add origin 10.10.10.1/test
git remote add origin \\10.10.10.1\test
git remote add origin \\\\10.10.10.1\\test
git remote add origin smb://10.10.10.1/test (git doesn't reconize the keyword 'smb')
```

What URL should I give in this case or is there any settings in Samba on Linux side that I need to modify? Thanks for all your time to read this much.

Tim

Comment: try to mount the windows share to local dir
http://askubuntu.com/questions/137011/how-to-mount-a-samba-shared-folder-ubuntu-x-ubuntu

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks for your help! I will try it and share the result later, thanks again!

Comment: I solved this problem by using SSH.